# Typescript Union Types

Tags: typescript

I am moving from Javascript to Typescript and am trying to create a class method which can take a JQuery object or an array of them. I am trying to use a union type but cannot seem to get the matching to work with the JQuery parameter:

```
setToGrey($items: JQuery[]|JQuery) {
    if ($items instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) {
            var $item = $items[i];
            this.resetIcon($item);
            $item.addClass(CSSClasses.TEXT_MUTED).find("span." + CSSClasses.GLYPHICON).addClass(CSSClasses.ICON_QUESTION_CICLE);
        }
    } else if ($items instanceof JQuery) {
        this.resetIcon($items);
        $items.addClass(CSSClasses.TEXT_MUTED).find("span." + CSSClasses.GLYPHICON).addClass(CSSClasses.ICON_QUESTION_CICLE);
    }
}
```

I cannot get the line:

```
} else if ($items instanceof JQuery) {
```

to work, the error comes up as Cannot find name 'JQuery'.

I'm not sure where my misunderstanding is. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```
if (Array.isArray($items)) { 
   // ...
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Please note that the types in the following signature

```
setToGrey($items: JQuery[]|JQuery) {
```

are only available at compile time. Whereas `instanceof` from

```
if ($items instanceof JQuery) {
```

is a run-time check where the content of your jQuery version (e.g. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js) applies (i.e. `jQuery` - notice the casings).

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts#L1154 definition file defines interface `JQuery` (again notice the casings) which is available only in compile time.

Comment: in the else block, is it necessary to cast $items to JQuery (i.e.: var $item = $items as JQuery) or will this be automatically inferred by typescript?

Comment: No, you don't need to cast the variable.